# "...as interesting as you think" vs "...as interesting as you'd think"?

Tags: grammar, tenses

> **Speaker A:** "You lived in Hawaii? Cool! How was it? Tell me, tell me.
>
> **Speaker B:** "Haha, it wasn't as interesting as you/you'd think.

What's the correct option in this case? Or should I have written *as you might think* instead?

Comment: It depends on what you mean. Use "you" if you know that Speaker A has presuppositions about Hawaii, and "you'd" if you don't.

Comment: Robusto is exactly right, but it also bears mentioning that the common phrase is definitely "as you'd think"

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in sense between the phrases "as you think" and as you'd think." If you say

> It wasn't as interesting as you think.

you are (as Robusto points out in a comment above) overtly claiming to know what Speaker A thinks about the topic in question. But even if you do know what Speaker A thinks on the subject, there is something aggressive and potentially rude about asserting that you do. The more polite approach is to make the response conditional, as in

> It wasn't as interesting as you'd think.

This expression sets up a hypothetical "you" who doesn't have first-hand experience of the topic being discussed—even though the hypothetical "you" and the actual "you" in all likelihood share this lack of experience. In effect, it is a short form of a much longer that we might express thought along these lines:

> It wasn't as interesting as you would think if the only information you had about living there was data from travel brochures, National Geographic TV specials, and beach movies.

From a politeness perspective, the crucial difference between the two options is the framing of the second statement as an open-ended conditional sentence. You can achieve a similar effect by using "might" with its implicit counterpoint "[or might not]":

> It wasn't as interesting as you might [or might not] think.

In either case, you give Speaker A leeway not to be one of those people who thinks something that isn't true—namely that living in Hawaii is inherently interesting. Saying

> It wasn't as interesting as you think.

flatly accuses Speaker A of being in error.